# parser.parse_args boolean parse "False" as True

Tags: python-3.x, boolean, argparse

When I run my python code with `-rm False` I still see `_REMOVE_ADS = True`.

How can I fix this?

```
parser.add_argument(
    "-rm",
    "--remove_ads",
    type=bool,
    required=False,
    default=False,
    help="Should remove disapproved ads. Default: false",
)
# TODO: Fix booleans
args = parser.parse_args()
_REMOVE_ADS = args.remove_ads
print(_REMOVE_ADS)
```

Comment: The `argparse` reference, warns, under the `type` header, **The bool() function is not recommended as a type converter. All it does is convert empty strings to False and non-empty strings to True. This is usually not what is desired.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because they are parsed as strings and any non-empty string is considered True by `bool`:

```
>>> bool("False")
True
```

To fix it, use a different type instead of `type=bool`, for Python < 3.10 there is [a standard lib option which can be used](https://docs.python.org/3.9/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.util.strtobool):

```
from distutils.util import strtobool
```

You can register this type with a name on a parser instance:

```
from distutils.util import strtobool

parser = ArgumentParser(...)
parser.register('type', 'boolean', strtobool)
parser.add_argument('-rm', type='boolean')
```

Alternatively, just make this option into a flag so it doesn't need to accept an argument at all, although note that this does change your CLI usage syntax:

```
parser.add_argument(
    "-rm", "--remove-ads",
    action="store_true",
    help="Should remove disapproved ads",
)
```

In Python 3.10 the [`distutils` module has been deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html). The [Migration Advice](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0632/#migration-advice) section of PEP-632 says there is no replacement for the `strtobool` function and you will need to re-implement the functionality yourself, but that should be easy enough (tweak as necessary):

```
def strtobool(val): 
    if val.lower().startswith("t"): 
        return True 
    elif val.lower().startswith("f"): 
        return False 
    raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("invalid boolean value: {!r}".format(val))
```

Comment: `just make it a flag so it doesn't ` how do I check that flag was used?

Comment: If the flag was used, `args.remove_ads` will be `True`.  If the flag was not provided, `args.remove_ads` will be `False`. And, in either case, `args.remove_ads` will _exist_ in the args namespace.